# Knockout - Can't figure out why the dependencies aren't being updated

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

Forgive me for not being able to upload anything to fiddle.

In short, i have a json array i want to get knockout to read and loop from, i have included the array next to when i start ko. This works happily, when i try and load some json with ajax it just fails.

I have this **object**:

```
   hutber.portfolio.ko = {
    init: function(){
        ko.applyBindings(new hutber.portfolio.ko.portfolioViewModel());
    },
    items: [],
    portfolioViewModel: function(){
        var self = this;

        var data = [
            {   "title":"poo"
            }
        ];

        self.items = ko.observableArray(data);

        var jamie = $.getJSON('/js/pages/portfolio.json').done(function(info){
            self.items = info;
        });
    }
};
hutber.portfolio.init();
```

**portfolio.json**

```
[
{   "title":"willies"
}
]
```

**markup**

```
        <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
            <li data-bind="text: title">
                 <h4>Volkswagen.co.uk</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

In my mind this should be working perfectly. I am updating `self.items` value with `self.items = info;` once my ajax request has finished.

Comment: Are you sure your AJAX call succeeds and the callback fires?

Comment: yup 100%, i just simpily tested with console.infoing 'jamie' :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callback is *replacing* the observable array and is not setting it correctly.  You need to call the observable passing in the object to set it.

```
    var jamie = $.getJSON('/js/pages/portfolio.json').done(function(info){
        self.items(info); // set the items to the info array
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're reassigning the value of `self.items` rather than updating the collection.

What you want to be doing is:

```
var jamie = $.getJSON('/js/pages/portfolio.json').done(function(info){
    info.forEach(function (x) { self.items.push(x); });
});
```

I've made the assumption that `info` is an array, if not just push it directly.

Comment: thanks for this as well, as expected this will not overwrite the data already added but append to the array.